# Import susy in Ember application

Tags: ember.js, susy

Have you tried to include Susy in your Ember application? I have tried it with different approaches but they don't work.

- Install susy as npm module using npm install susy.
- Install susy with the ember-cli.
- Install susy and use eyeglass.

The build finishes ok but there is a problem with the import (it is not importing the susy file). I'm trying the options below:

```
@import 'node_modules/susy/sass/susy.scss'

@import '../../node_modules/susy/sass/susy.scss'
@import 'susy' (with eyeglass)
```

Have you run into the same issue before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot simply import npm modules into your app, take a look at https://simplabs.com/blog/2017/02/13/npm-libs-in-ember-cli.html

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what suzy is but:

1. if you need to use a node module that was not adopted to run in browser and not available as ember module, you can use [ember-browserify](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify).
2. If you need to use some library that runs in browser but distributed only through npm or if you want to use npm instead of bower, you can use [ember-cli-node-assets](https://github.com/dfreeman/ember-cli-node-assets)

**UPD**: To import 3rd-party scss files you can use `includePath` option of ember-cli-sass as shown in [this example](https://github.com/aexmachina/ember-cli-sass#example)